# How to rewrite this sum of products using Linq or Extension functions?

Tags: c#, linq

The code:

```
decimal bidTotal = 0m;
decimal askTotal = 0m;
decimal closeTotal = 0m;


foreach (IETFComponent component in components.Values)
{
    bidTotal += component.BidPrice * component.Pricingshares;
    askTotal += component.AskPrice * component.Pricingshares;
    closeTotal += component.ClosePrice * component.Pricingshares;
}

result.NAVBidPrice = bidTotal / this.Units;
result.NAVAskPrice = askTotal / this.Units;
result.NAVClosePrice = closeTotal / this.Units;
```

So I think there must be a better way to write this either using LINQ or one of the Extension functions, but I'm not sure.  I don't care about the intermediate values at all.  (The `components` object is a Dictionary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to apply some accumulator function over components. But if you want to accumulate several different values, you should use accumulator object which holds all required values. With LINQ it will look like:

```
var result = components.Values.Aggregate(
    new { BidTotal = 0m, AskTotal = 0m, CloseTotal = 0m },
    (a, c) => new
    {
        BidTotal = a.BidTotal + c.BidPrice * c.Pricingshares,
        AskTotal = a.AskTotal + c.AskPrice * c.Pricingshares,
        CloseTotal = a.CloseTotal + c.ClosePrice * c.Pricingshares
    });
```

But its neither readable, nor efficient (creating anonymous objects instead of simple incrementing values). You can create custom accumulator:

```
public class ComponentTotals
{
    public ComponentTotals Add(IETFComponent component)
    {
        Bid += component.BidPrice * component.Pricingshares;
        Ask += component.AskPrice * component.Pricingshares;
        Close += component.ClosePrice * component.Pricingshares;
        return this;
    }

    public decimal Bid { get; private set; }
    public decimal Ask { get; private set; }
    public decimal Close { get; private set; }
}
```

Then accumulating values will look like:

```
ComponentTotals result = 
       components.Values.Aggregate(new ComponentTotals(), (ct, c) => ct.Add(c));
```

But I would definitely go with simple *foreach* loop here.

Comment: That was very helpful in clarifying the Linq/Func syntax for this.  I agreed with your point that using this syntax is worse than leaving the loop.